# How to play sound when a value is changed in a dynamic javascript table?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a dynamic table that auto-refreshes every 5 seconds, created using javascript. I want to play a notification sound when a value in 'failed column' increases. I can't frame the strategy to go about it. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

This is my ajaxcall

```
 ajaxCall = function () {
    $.get('/c/web/jas/getdetails', function (data) {
       var jsondata=JSON.parse(data);
        GenerateTable(data);
        setTimeout('ajaxCall()', 5000);
    });
};
```

This is my table function

```
 GenerateTable = function (json) {
    var ar = JSON.parse(json);
    var col = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        for (var key in ar[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }        
    var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    table.border = "1";  

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        tr = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);                
            tabCell.innerHTML = ar[i][col[j]];
        }
    }
    var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
    dvTable.innerHTML = "";
    dvTable.appendChild(table);
}
```

[image: This is my table]
This is my table which refreshes every 5 seconds.

Comment: You can use the WebAudio API to generate the sound (https://www.sitepoint.com/web-audio-api-add-sound-to-web-page/). Where abouts in your code is the value in the 'failed' column increasing?

Comment: This is the json data that's coming in `[
 {
 "Location":"1",
 "Delivery":"RU",
 "Pending":"597",
 "Running":"127",
 "Failed":"361",
 "Completed":"116"
 },{
 "Location":"1",
 "Delivery":"RE",
 "Pending":"54",
 "Running":"143",
 "Failed":"3",
 "Completed":"201"
 },]` I'll check out the WebAudio API btw

Comment: Sorry, I meant where in your code are you parsing that JSON and updating the DOM?

Comment: In the front-end application. The url in the ajax call directs to the controller action which fetches the data from the web service. If that's what you're asking ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ok, well that's where you'll be wanting to add the code to make the sound. Something approaching the first example in that article should work. I can add it as an answer if that's helpful.

Comment: Please do. Thanks once again. CHeers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Web Audio API to generate sound in the browser. It has reasonably [good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api) (apart from in IE).

The Web Audio API provides a source node called [OscillatorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode) which allows frequencies to be generated against a specified waveform.

For example, to make a small, dull beep (something approaching a warning sound in your example) you could do:

```
const context = new AudioContext();
const oscillatorNode = context.createOscillator();
oscillatorNode.type = 'triangle';
oscillatorNode.frequency.value = 150;
oscillatorNode.connect(context.destination);
oscillatorNode.start();
oscillatorNode.stop(context.currentTime + 0.5);
```

Here, `triangle` is a predefined waveform that can be specified via an instance's `type` property and `frequency` determines the pitch. You specify the duration as an argument to `stop()` (in this case, half a second).

AudioNodes are cheap to create, thus the design of the Web Audio API encourages developers to recreate them as and when they’re needed. This means that in your case, you would do all of this in the code that handles updating DOM to increase the values in the failed column.

This is a very informative reference to the Web Audio API if you'd like to read more, or see more practical examples: [Web Audio API: Add Bandwidth-Friendly Sound to Your Web Page](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-audio-api-add-sound-to-web-page/)